# How to execute XSLT with multiple input files and single output file

Tags: xml, xslt, command-line, xslt-2.0, saxon

I want to use XSLT to read all the XML files within a subdirectory and output the results to a single XML file, but I'm not sure how to execute the transformation.

The syntax below works if both the source uri and the output uri are directories, but it doesn't work if the source uri is a directory while the output uri is a filename.

I don't think the spaces in the uri are an issue. The syntax below does work for me, provided that the uris are in quotation marks (and provided that the source and the output are both filenames or both directories).

I'm using the Saxon HE processor, but I am willing to use another tool if necessary.

java -jar c:\saxon\saxon9he.jar -s:"C:\Temp\2011 Valid XML" -o:"C:\Temp\LookupTables.xml" -xsl:"C:\Temp\LookupTables.xsl"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the stylesheet needs to take the input into account, for instance by using the `collection` function http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!sourcedocs/collections

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('file:///C:Temp/dir?select=*.xml')/*"/>
  </root>
</xsl:template>
```

and then you run Saxon with the `-it:main` command line option to start with the template `main` that pulls in all `*.xml` files in that directory.

You of course then need to make sure there are templates processing and transforming the nodes in the files as needed but as you have not provided any example of the XML structure there is not much we can suggest to help with that.

Comment: Thanks, the XSLT is now executing. I'm now getting an error message that the requested template "main" does not exist, but I'll put that into a separate question.